# Закрепить приложение на Android

Tags: java, android

День!
Есть планшет на android с установленным на нём приложением обратной связи. Суть такая - лежит такой планшет на кассе в магазине и каждый желающий может воспользоваться этим планшетом для коммуникации с, предположим, директором этого магазина.

Нужно, чтобы пользователь не смог закрыть это приложение и не смог выйти из него.
При перезагрузке приложение стартует вместе с системой.

Есть идеи как реализовать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак давайте по порядку:

1. Чтобы приложение нельзя было закрыть, я бы вам посоветовал заблокировать все аппаратные клавиши планшета. Чтобы нельзя было например клавишей home просто свернуть приложение в трей, либо клавишей назад с него выйти. Вот например вопрос на enSO по этой теме - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507063/home-button-disable/6530002#6530002) + [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android).
2. Вторая часть вопроса. Чтобы ваше приложение стартовало сразу после загрузки вам нужно отловить загрузку устройства и дальше стартовать приложение. Вот например есть вопрос - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056570/how-to-autostart-an-android-application).

Надеюсь предоставленные ресурсы помогут в решении вашей задачи. Если возникнут сложности или будет что-то не понятно, то постараюсь помочь. Удачи :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну самый простой способ это сделать так:

С планшета удаляете все приложения(не системные) - это в принципе не обязательно.

Главное:

1 - Удаляете стандартный лаунчер.

2- В манифесте своего приложение пишите что та типа(ваше приложение становится типа лаунчером, при нажатии home будет открываться он, при старте тоже)

```
<activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

3- Чтобы не могли входить в настройки, можете удалить из system/app - system-ui.apk (это шторка)